# Probability of Achieving a Count Level in Time Series Data

Tags: time-series, probability, cumulative-distribution-function

I have some time-series data that displays a count value for every day:

[image]

These count values begin at 1 or -1 and will continue to count up (or down) if conditions in the time series are met.  If the conditions are not met consecutively, then the count value can return to -1, 0, or 1 (to initiate the next count series). 0 values do not represent the beginning of a count series, but rather an instance when none of the directional count conditions are met; functionally, an NA value.

My question is, with this data, is it possible to determine the probability of a future count value being reached once a minimum threshold is met? For example, what is the confidence that I can have that a count of -3 [10/16/2006 in the above data] will then make it down to a count of -6 [10/19/2006]?

I've plotted the distribution of these counts for a much longer data series. The chart below shows that a count of up to -20 was reached at least once between 01-01-2000 and 12-31-2006! With regards to my probability question, I was thinking that maybe I could sum the area between -3 and -6 to determine the probability that a -3 will reach a -6, but that doesn't feel right.

[image]

I sincerely appreciate your help!

Comment: A Markov chain might be an appropriate model, but--crucially--the operational meaning of the "NA" values must be understood. It seems they are not the same as missing values. Perhaps you could explain what the underlying data really are and how your series actually is derived from them? Do you have access to the underlying data?

Comment: thank you @whuber! i do not have access to the underlying data of the count value nor am i aware of the algorithmic construction of these counts, but i do understand that these counts are typically applied to financial price series. so, the negative counts represent a negative shift in momentum and the positive counts indicate positive momentum. a 0 reading is neither positive or negative trending, but rather a range bound period in the market. a note about the density plot: since these counts are consecutive, it makes sense that the distribution is bimodally distributed around 1 and -1